# Searching for a CVS command client

Tags: windows, command-line, console, cvs

I'm looking for a CVS client which works from the console. All windows clients that I've found are GUI's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) there is command line [CVS](http://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?grep=cvs) available. It's pretty large package just for CVS client, but you'll get other useful things too, for example standard unix command line tools like `sed`, `grep` and so on (of course you don't have to use those ever).

You can also run Cygwin tools from normal Windows command prompt (`CMD.EXE`), if you add Cygwin binaries to your PATH variable (in Windows 7, Control Panel -> System -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables -> search "Path" from "System variables" box and add ";C:\cygwin\bin;C:\cygwin\usr\bin").

Comment: +1 for Cygwin, though you can tune Cygwin setup.exe (somewhat) to limit all the extras of cygwin.